# Referencing Textbox Input from Access Form in VB Module

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm currently working in access creating a database that will send all of the people I've designated an email every month with files relevant to them and am trying to reference a textbox entry where the user will enter a date from an Access form in an access module. More specifically, I'm attempting to grab the text from the textbox and put it into the file path that I'm attempting to save each file to.

Instead of babbling on, here is a sample of what's not working in my code:

```
    Dim timestamp as String
    Dim territory as String
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Sales Email"
    Forms![Sales Email]![FromDate].SetFocus

    territory = rs.fields(1)
    timestamp = Forms![Sales Email]![FromDate].Text

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "TheNewQueryDef", acFormatXLS, "\\cletus\data\accounting\KRISTEN\Monthly Sales for " & territory & " " & timestamp & ".xls", False
```

Specifically it's telling me: "Run-time error '2302': Microsoft Office Access can't save the output data to the file you've selected."

Side note: Before I began working on adding in the timestamp variable (which I'm trying to get to reference the date entered in the form's textbox) to the file path, it worked perfectly how I needed it to.

Any input would be greatly appreciated! And sorry if I'm not clear - I'm still somewhat of a beginner when it comes to code. If more clarification is needed, please say so.

Comment: that is not VB.NET code; it looks like access-vba

Comment: That is what it is, sorry about that. I mixed it up.

Comment: Check the full path of the output file which you're using in `DoCmd.OutputTo`.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I don't; please explain, if you wouldn't mind

Comment: I figured it out and checked it. The file path seems to be correct. Like I said, before I began trying to add in the timestamp variable into the file name, the code worked exactly how I needed it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably your `timestamp` string contains characters that are illegal in a Windows file name,
e.g. `/` or `:`

If it's a date with time, try something like this:

```
timestamp = Format(Forms![Sales Email]![FromDate].Value, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-nn-ss")
```

which also makes for better sorting.

---

Note: by using `.Value` instead of `.Text` you don't need this line:

```
Forms![Sales Email]![FromDate].SetFocus
```